# Testing divisibility of a list and appending if prime

Tags: python-3.x, primes

I'm writing a short snippet for a class that is supposed to run through a given list of numbers and append any primes. Right now it is returning all numbers in the range though.

I've found examples online for how to do this, but wanted to try it myself but I've seem to hit a wall... Here is my code:

```
from random import randrange
from time import sleep

def prime():
    user_num = eval(input("Input a number: "))
    list_prime = []
    for i in range(2,user_num):
        if (i % 2) == 1 and\
            (i % 3) == 1 and\
            (i % 4) == 1 and\
            (i % 5) == 1 and\
            (i % 6) == 1 and\
            (i % 7) == 1 and\
            (i % 8) == 1 and\
            (i % 9) == 1 or\
            i == 2:
            list_prime.append(i)

if list_prime == '':
    print('No prime numbers.')
if list_prime != '':
    print('\nPrime numbers from 1 to ' + str(user_num) + ': ' + str(list_prime))

sleep(1)
print('\nClosing console in 60 seconds...')
sleep(60)

prime()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As he said, you werent correctly checking for prime numbers.

```
from random import randrange
from time import sleep

list_prime = []
user_num = 0

def prime():
    user_num = eval(input("Input a number: "))
    for i in range(2,user_num):
        j = 2
        isprime = 1
        while (j <= i/2):
            if (i % j == 0):
                isprime = 0
                break
            j+=1
        if (isprime == 1):
            list_prime.append(i)

prime()
if list_prime == '':
    print('No prime numbers.')
if list_prime != '':
    print('\nPrime numbers from 1 to ' + str(user_num) + ': ' + str(list_prime))

sleep(1)
print('\nClosing console in 60 seconds...')
sleep(60)
```

Comment: Thanks that works perfectly! Took me a minute to comprehend the syntax but it's very clever. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Checking if the result of a modulo operation is 1 is not the correct approach. For example, 6 % 5 is 1, but 6 definitely isn't a prime number. Instead, for each suspect N you should check that no number X exists such that N % X == 0.

A wildly sub-optimal implementation could look like this:

```
list_prime = []
for i in range(2, user_num):
    if all(n % x for x in list_prime):
        list_prime.append(i)
```

Comment: Thanks. What makes this sub-optimal?

Comment: Algorithmically, it performs as O(n^2) and heuristically, it involves a lot of unnecessary work.  For example, if you've already tested if a number is divisible by 2 and 3 then testing for divisibility by 4, 6, 9, and any other multiples of 2 and 3 is pointless.